# Mini batch gradient descent weights update

Tags: python, numpy, conv-neural-network

I try to convert this Kaggle CNN from scratch from stochastic gradient descent to mini batch gradient descent, but it doesn't converge.

Original stochastic version, it works fine.
https://www.kaggle.com/milan400/cnn-from-scratch-numpy

My mini batch version:

- Training sample numbers = 1000
- Mini batch size = 100
- Within each mini batch, I saved the delta of gradient for each sample, and took average over the 100 samples, and then updated the weight. So the delta of weights are calculated for 100 times, but weights are only updated once for each mini batch.
- Below is my code, really appreciate if anyone could point out which part is wrong.

```
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
from IPython.core.display import display,Image
from string import Template
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import IPython.display
import warnings 

# update d_l_d_filters, size: 3 x 3 x num_filters
# im_region: 3 x 3
class Conv:
    def __init__(self, num_filters):
        self.num_filters = num_filters
        self.filters = np.random.randn(num_filters,3,3)/9
        self.d_l_d_filters_acc = np.zeros(self.filters.shape)
        
    def iterate_regions(self, image):
        h,w = image.shape
        
        for i in range(h-2):
            for j in range(w-2):
                im_region = image[i:(i+3),j:(j+3)]
                yield im_region, i, j
        
    def forward(self,input):
        self.last_input = input
        h,w = input.shape
        output = np.zeros((h-2,w-2,self.num_filters))
        
        for im_regions, i, j in self.iterate_regions(input):
            output[i,j]=np.sum(im_regions * self.filters, axis=(1,2))
        return output
                
    def backprop(self, d_l_d_out, learn_rate):
        # d_l_d_out is loss gradient for this layer's outputs
        d_l_d_filters = np.zeros(self.filters.shape)
        
        for im_region, i, j in self.iterate_regions(self.last_input):
            for f in range(self.num_filters):
                d_l_d_filters[f] += d_l_d_out[i,j,f]*im_region
        
        self.d_l_d_filters_acc = self.d_l_d_filters_acc + d_l_d_filters
        #self.filters -= learn_rate * d_l_d_filters
        
        return None

class Relu:
    def forward(self, input):
        self.last_input = input
        h,w,num_filters = input.shape
        output = np.zeros((h,w,num_filters))
        for n in range(num_filters):
            for i in range(h):
                for j in range(w):
                    if input[i,j,n]>0:
                        output[i,j,n]=input[i,j,n]
        return output
                        
    def backprop(self, d_l_d_out):
        d_l_d_input = np.zeros(self.last_input.shape)
        h,w,num_filters = self.last_input.shape
        
        for n in range(num_filters):
            for i in range(h):
                for j in range(w):
                    if self.last_input[i,j,n]>0:
                        d_l_d_input[i,j,n]=d_l_d_out[i,j,n]
        return d_l_d_input
        

# update d_l_d_input, input size * num_filters
# d_l_d_out output (size//2) * num_filters
class MaxPool:
    def iterate_regions(self,image):
        h,w,_ = image.shape    
        new_h = h//2
        new_w = w//2
        for i in range(new_h):
            for j in range(new_w):
                im_region = image[(i*2):(i*2+2),(j*2):(j*2+2)]
                yield im_region,i,j
    
    def forward(self,input):
        self.last_input = input
        h,w,num_filters = input.shape
        output = np.zeros((h//2,w//2,num_filters))
        
        for im_region,i,j in self.iterate_regions(input):
            output[i,j]=np.amax(im_region, axis=(0,1))
            
        return output
    
    def backprop(self,d_l_d_out):
        d_l_d_input = np.zeros(self.last_input.shape)
        for im_region, i, j in self.iterate_regions(self.last_input):
            h,w,f = im_region.shape 
            amax = np.amax(im_region, axis=(0,1))
            
            for i2 in range(h):
                for j2 in range(w):
                    for f2 in range(f):
                        if(im_region[i2,j2,f2] == amax[f2]):
                            d_l_d_input[i*2+i2,j*2+j2,f2]=d_l_d_out[i,j,f2]
                            break;
                            
        return d_l_d_input
    
# update w, size: input_len x nodes of softmax
# update b, size: nodes of softmax
# update a, size: input_len (flattened from 2d last_input_shape)
class Softmax:
    def __init__(self, input_len, nodes):
        self.weights = np.random.randn(input_len, nodes)/input_len
        self.biases = np.zeros(nodes)
        self.d_l_d_w_acc = np.zeros(self.weights.shape)
        self.d_l_d_b_acc = np.zeros(nodes)
    
    # return softmax outputs, size: nodes
    def forward(self, input):
        self.last_input_shape = input.shape
        input = input.flatten()
        self.last_input = input
        input_len, nodes = self.weights.shape
        totals = np.dot(input, self.weights) + self.biases
        self.last_totals = totals
        exp = np.exp(totals)
        return(exp/np.sum(exp,axis=0))
    
    # d_l_d_out is final gradient: -SIGMA(y_hat * log(y_c))=-log(y_c)
    # only category softmax output is 1, others are all zeros
    def backprop(self, d_l_d_out, learn_rate):
        for i,gradient in enumerate(d_l_d_out):
            if(gradient==0):
                continue
            
            t_exp = np.exp(self.last_totals) # softmax output
            S = np.sum(t_exp)
            
            #all softmax output gradient
            d_out_d_t = -t_exp[i]*t_exp/(S**2)
             
            #then overwrite the hot category one
            d_out_d_t[i] = t_exp[i]*(S-t_exp[i])/(S**2)
            
            #initialize the gradients of w, b, a for the multiplication base
            d_t_d_w = self.last_input # dw will be multipled with a
            d_t_d_b = 1 # db will be multipled with 1
            d_t_d_inputs = self.weights # da will be multipled with w
        
            # d_l_d_t is the delta(final gradient) to delta(softmax input)
            # although only one category contributes to final gradient,
            # from final gradient to each softmax node, there is a gradient
            d_l_d_t = gradient * d_out_d_t
            
            # propagate gradient from softmax input to w,b,a
            d_l_d_w = d_t_d_w[np.newaxis].T @ d_l_d_t[np.newaxis] # size: input x nodes
            d_l_d_b = d_l_d_t * d_t_d_b
            d_l_d_inputs = d_t_d_inputs @ d_l_d_t
            
            # update w and b
            #self.weights -= learn_rate * d_l_d_w
            #self.biases -= learn_rate * d_l_d_b
            
            self.d_l_d_w_acc = np.add(self.d_l_d_w_acc, d_l_d_w)
            self.d_l_d_b_acc = np.add(self.d_l_d_b_acc, d_l_d_b)
            
            return d_l_d_inputs.reshape(self.last_input_shape)
        
from keras.datasets import mnist

(train_X, train_y), (test_X, test_y) = mnist.load_data()

train_images = train_X[:1000]
train_labels = train_y[:1000]
test_images = test_X[:1000]
test_labels = test_y[:1000]


conv = Conv(8)
pool = MaxPool()
softmax = Softmax(13*13*8, 10)
relu_en = 0
relu = Relu()

batch_size = 100
batch_num = int(len(train_images)/batch_size)
lr = 0.005

def forward(image, label):
    out = conv.forward((image/255)-0.5)
    if relu_en==1:
        out = relu.forward(out)
    out = pool.forward(out)
    out = softmax.forward(out) # softmax output, size: nodes
    
    loss = -np.log(out[label]) # one hot
    acc = 1 if(np.argmax(out)==label) else 0
    
    return out, loss, acc

def train(im, label, lr=0.005):
    out, loss, acc = forward(im, label)
    gradient = np.zeros(10)
    gradient[label] = -1/out[label]
    
    gradient = softmax.backprop(gradient, lr)
    gradient = pool.backprop(gradient)
    if relu_en==1:
        gradient = relu.backprop(gradient)
    gradient = conv.backprop(gradient, lr)
    
    return loss, acc

def update_nn(lr, batch_size):
    softmax.d_l_d_w_acc /= batch_size
    softmax.d_l_d_b_acc /= batch_size
    conv.d_l_d_filters_acc /= batch_size
    softmax.weights -= lr * softmax.d_l_d_w_acc
    softmax.biases -= lr * softmax.d_l_d_b_acc
    conv.filters -= lr * conv.d_l_d_filters_acc

for epoch in range(3):
    print('----EPOCH %d ---'%(epoch+1))
    permutation = np.random.permutation(len(train_images))
    train_images = train_images[permutation]
    train_labels = train_labels[permutation]
    
    loss = 0
    num_correct = 0
    
    for bi in range(batch_num):
        loss = 0
        num_correct = 0
        conv.d_l_d_filters_acc = np.zeros(conv.filters.shape)
        softmax.d_l_d_w_acc = np.zeros(softmax.weights.shape)
        softmax.d_l_d_b_acc = np.zeros(softmax.biases.shape)
        for ii in range(batch_size):
            i = bi*batch_size+ii
            im = train_images[i] 
            label = train_labels[i]
            
            l,acc = train(im, label)
            loss+=l
            num_correct += acc
        
        update_nn(lr, batch_size)
        
        print('[Step %d] Past 100 steps: Average Loss %.3f | Accuracy: %d%%' %(i + 1, loss / 100, num_correct))
```

Comment: I found it works after changing epoch = 3 to epoch = 300. Do we expect rate of convergence to be ~100 times slower if we use mini batch size = 100 (instead of 1)?

Answer (score 0):

add momentum to gradient descent it will converge fast.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).